# UIPickerView next to UIDatePicker not rendering per IB?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Why isn't the actually simulator rendering of my view not matching that in interface builder.  I have a UIPickerView next to UIDatePicker looking good in IB, but not in the simulator.  In particular the large gap inbetween, and the fact the right hand side fo the time picker goes off the edge of the screen.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `UIDataPicker` always re-renders itself with a static bounds (one landscape mode, one for portrait). So you can change its position but not shape. I've bumped into this fact recently.

Comment: oh...So I guess to get this compressed view then I'd probably have to use a multi-section UIPickerView and setup the hour/minute sections in addition to day?